Monitor is a unknown display
I have changed my GPU and now one of my monitors it not working.
I am on Ubuntu 24.04 and have now a RX 7600 XT 16GB GPU.
I did try to restart and re slot my GPU with no effect i still have 2 working monitors and did switch them to no effect.
I am still new to Linux so a rooky mistake is possible.

What GPU did you have before you switched?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I had A RTX 3050.
